# ASP.net MVC: Input String Was Not In Correct Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to write to a database and am getting the "Input String Was Not In Correct Format" error. I'm assuming it's the data types on the last two columns but I'm not sure how to change. In SQL Server, they are both of the money datatype. Code below:

```
string query = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
                        query = "INSERT INTO Upload(Email, TimeStamp, EmployeeId, Name, Title, Department, Race, Gender, AnnualizedBase, AnnualizedTCC) VALUES ('" 
                            + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() + "', "
                            + " '" + DateTime.Now + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() + "', "
                            + " '" + result.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString() + "', "
                            + Convert.ToInt32(result.Tables[0].Rows[i][6]) + ", "
                            + Convert.ToInt32(result.Tables[0].Rows[i][7])
                            + ")";
                        con.Open();
                       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: Please look ASAP how to write parameterized queries. You will save yourself from these errors, from this mess of code and from Sql Injection

Comment: Please take a look at [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If I'm understanding correctly, my insert query will look something like INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (@email, @field2, @field3), and each field will be defined like this: var emailparam = new SqlParameter("Email", SqlDbType.Text);
                        emailparam.Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); -- Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *Input string was not in correct format* is most likely caused by one of the values in your column not being convertible to an `int`. If the datatype in SQL is `money` then you should try and convert to a `decimal` and not an `int`. Try this for each row:

```
decimal num;
if (decimal.TryParse(result.Tables[0].Rows[i][6], out num))
{
    // use num because it is indeed a decimal (money in SQL)
}
else
{
    // What do you want to do? Log it and continue to next row?
}
```

Also please read [Bobby Tales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and [example of paratmetrized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).